# How to write this T-SQL WHERE condition?

Tags: t-sql

I've got two tables:

```
TableA
    Col1
    Col2
TableB
    Col3
    Col4
```

I want to join them together:

```
SELECT * from TableA join TableB ON (...)
```

Now, in place of `...` I need to write an expression that evaluates to:

1. If Col3 is not null, then true iif Col1==Col3; otherwise
2. If Col3 is null, then true iif Col2==Col4

What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ON (Col1=Col3 OR (Col3 IS NULL AND Col2=Col4))
```

should do the trick (if Col3 is null, Col1=Col3 cannot evalutate to TRUE)

Comment: Your OR and AND conditions might be confusing.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I thought that there should be an easier way than just a bunch of deeply nested case-when statements! :)

Comment: @Randolph Potter - makes sense to me. I'll just add parenthesis around the AND condition.

Comment: Randoph: AND before OR... for some people, it's as clear as * before +; other people prefere parenthesis for clearness.

Comment: To be honest, I can never remember which comes first, but the idea behind this solution was so clear that there was no need to clarify. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB 
   ON Col1 = Col3
      OR (Col3 IS NULL AND Col2 = Col4)
```